# Is there a way to monitor a GrandStream registration status?

Tags: monitoring, voip, sip

I have a provider locked GrandStream device and I had some issues where the device would unregister itself during the night and I would lose my phone line.

I cannot afford to not notice when the VoIP phone is down. I need to know it as soon as possible to troubleshoot/reboot devices if needed to restore the line.

The device is a fairly basic GrandStream HT800 and serve for only a specific type of calls.

It there a way to monitor using command line, network traffic or by any other means if the device is registered with the provider? (I mean, there is a LED light turned on when the phone is registered but I would like something more technological than to have to look at the light every 30 minutes)

I do not have access to the web panel - it is password protected by the provider.

I tried looking if there was some kind of public api provided by the box that I could query every minutes but I didn't find anything.

I currently use a Raspberry Pi with Home Assistant and Pi Hole to monitor the status of the network and the devices attached to it, if it can help... It served me well so far.

Comment: Pi Hole is probably not going to help here, I am assuming you are just using it as a DNS server and possibly for DHCP. But the SIP traffic is not going through the Raspberry Pi. If you had the Raspberry Pi acting as a network tap then you could monitor (sniff) the traffic using tcpdump or Wireshark. The phone must be sending SIP requests on port 5060 at regular intervals. When the requests stop, you know there is something wrong and you can trigger an alert of some sort. The issue could be the router or simply poor cabling.

Comment: Thanks! Yea I know the PiHole records only the DNS traffic. So in theory I could try and write a script running in the router to check for SIP requests on port 5060 comming from the box and if the requests stops, it's sign that something is wrong? Any idea in general how much requests/interval of requests are for SIP phone?

Comment: Another thought: assuming that your Raspberry Pi acts as DHCP server for the devices in your local network, and your Grandstream phone uses a hostname such as sip.provider.com instead of a hardcoded IP addresss - then you could see the DNS requests made to sip.provider.com or whatever, and how frequently they are made. Again, assuming your phone gets an IP address (and other network settings) from PI hole and not from the router direct. Since you do not have access to the web interface of the phone, putting the Pi in the middle could at least give you some insight.

Comment: Oh that could be a good idea. I isolated the PiHole and redirected all DNS traffic through it, so yea I should be able to see when requests are made to the server. :D Thanks